# Is $x^5+x^3+x+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I need to find an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3$ of degree 5. To do this, I just tried some polynomials that have no roots mod 3, so if it were reducible, it would factor as an irreducible polynomial of degree 2, and another one of degree 3.

I tried the polynomial $f=x^5+x^3+x+1$ and found that $f(-1)=f(1)=f(0)=1\mod 3$ so it has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$. Then, I tried to divide this polynomial by the second-degree polynomials to see if it would result in a possible third-degree polynomial. The irreducible polynomials of degree 2 in $\mathbb{F}_3$ are:

- $f_1=x^2-x-1$
- $f_2=x^2+x-1$
- $f_3=x^2+1$

Dividing by $f_1$ gives $x^3+x^2+1$ but then leaves a rest term of $2x+2$ in long division: $(x^5+x^3+x+1)-(x^2-x-1)(x^3+x^2+1)=2x+2$

Similarly, dividing by $f_2$ gives $f-f_2(x^3-x^2-1)=2x+2$, and dividing by $f_3$ gives $f-f_3*x^3=x-2$.

From this, I concluded that $f$ is not divisible by any polynomial of degree 2 in $\mathbb{F}_3$, and therefore cannot split, but I was not sure if this is a solid argument. Besides, this seems like a bit of a random way to find such a polynomial, so any other (simpler) approach to find an (any) irreducible polynomial of degree 5 in $\mathbb{F}_3$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds good. Well done!

Comment: It's not a random way at all. What you've done is analogous to checking divisibility by primes up to the square root in primality testing.

Comment: @HwChu thank you!

Comment: Chiming in with @eyeballfrog. Finding irreducible polynomials over a prime field is not at all unlike finding prime numbers. It is marginally easier: 1) we can describe a few sparse lists of irreducible polynomials, but no comparable formulas producing only prime numbers is known, 2) the equivalent of the Riemann hypothesis is a theorem in the polynomial case, 3) definitive polynomial time test of irreducibility is easier to describe in the polynomial case. But for the purposes of paper and pencil work they are very much comparable tasks.